# How make the legend to pop up over the Hightcharts element on hover

Tags: jquery, highcharts, typescript2.0

I am looking for a way to show a popping legend on hover over the donut. Here is my code in the [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yzXLz7AIDoWa1Pzxxl4k?p=preview).

I have a similar example done in the plunker by using highcharts and javascript. The problem I am facing is to make it work in Angular2 component. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3ehrgge7/6/) is the to  it.

---

```
 @Component({

  selector: 'my-app',

  styles: [`
          chart {
            display: block;
          }
          button {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 25px;
          }
          legend-label-md {
        font-family: ProximaNova-Reg-webfont;
        width: 200px;

         pull-left {
        float: left !important;
    }
    pull-right {
        float: right !important;
    }
      `],
  template: `
            <chart  [options]="options" >
            </chart>
        `
})


class AppComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.options = {
      title: { text: ' ' },
      colors: ['#599EB5', '#436899', '#8FB95B', '#5AB782', '#47C3B9', '#BE78CB', '#e4d354', '#2b908f', '#f45b5b', '#91e8e1'],
      chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        animation: false
      },
      plotOptions: {
        pie: {
          innerSize: '40%',
          allowPointSelect: true,
          cursor: 'pointer',
          dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
          },
          showInLegend: true,
          states: {
            hover: {
              halo: {
                size: 0
              }
            }
          }
        },
        series: {
          animation: false,
          point: {
            events: {
              mouseOver: function (events) {
                const p = events.points

                console.log(p);
              },
              mouseOut: function (events) {
                //alert("mouse out");
              },

              legendItemClick: function (e) {
                console.log(this);
                return false;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      tooltip: {

        enabled: false
      },
      legend: {
        useHTML: true,
        enabled: true,
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        layout: 'vertical',
        x: 0,
        y: 30,
        symbolHeight: 12,
        itemMarginBottom: 1,
        symbolWidth: 25,
        symbolRadius: 1,
        labelFormatter: function () {
          return '<div style="width:180px"><span class="pull-left" style= "font-weight: 500; padding-bottom: 5px">' + this.name +
            '</span><span class="pull-right" style= "font-weight: 500" >' + this.value +
            '</span></div> ';
        },
        title: {
          text: ' Issues<br/><span style="font-size: 9px; color: #666; font-weight: normal">Total: 2000</span>'
          //Click event on 2000 
          // call donut service's get total info. Need not have to pass any variable. 

        },
      },
      series: [{
        data: [{ name: 'AA Test_long_name_for_testing_purpose', value: '5,044', y: 5044 },
        { name: 'BB Test', value: '5,044', y: 5044 },
        { name: 'CC Test', value: '5,355', y: 5355 },
        { name: 'DD Test', value: '5,672', y: 56721 },
        { name: 'EE Test', value: '9,874', y: 98743 }],
        allowPointSelect: true
      }]
    };
  }

  options: Object;
  chart: Object;
}
```

Comment: What do mean by saying 'legend to pop up over the Highcharts element on hover'? There's no legend in the fiddle that you provided. Do you mean tooltip?: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/tooltip

Comment: Do you want to show the pie section name of that particular portion on hover over that section or what? If that is the case just remove the `tooltip : {enabled: false }` from the chartOptions

Comment: @Kamil Kulig - In my first plunker example, i have the legend with names aa, bb, cc ,  and i want small square boxes next to the names should get highlighted when i hover my mouse over the corresponding pie sections in chart. When mouse is at  pink color in chart , then aa square box should get highlighted. I hope i made clear the doubt. And in second fiddle i just shared like this is how it should be but yes it does not have any legend. sorry my bad for this example.

Comment: @Gaurav Pandvia - Thank you for the suggestion, but i want when i hover over chart , corresponding square boxes should get highlighted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the chart options that you should use. I have added two events one is mouseOver and mouseOut inside series -> point -> events in which the corresponding legend item gets a class and on mouse out I remove that class.

Updated plnkr [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/SrdcWSc6KbnzFjFLtF2q?p=preview)

```
    this.options = {
        title : { text : ' ' },
        colors: ['#599EB5', '#436899', '#8FB95B', '#5AB782', '#47C3B9', '#BE78CB', '#e4d354', '#2b908f', '#f45b5b', '#91e8e1'],
         chart: {
            type: 'pie',
             animation: false
        },



        plotOptions: {
            pie: {

                innerSize: '40%',
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                showInLegend: true,
                states: {
                  hover: {
                    halo: {
                      size: 0
                    }
                  }
                }
            },
               series: {
                animation: false,
                point: {
                    events: {

                        legendItemClick: function (e) {
                           console.log(this);
                            return false;
                        },
                        mouseOver: function (e) {
                          e.target.legendItem.element.classList.add('highlight');

                           console.log(this);
                            return false;
                        },

                        mouseOut: function (e){
                          e.target.legendItem.element.classList.remove('highlight');

                           console.log(this);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        tooltip: {

            enabled: false
        },

        legend: {
            useHTML: true,
            enabled: true,
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            layout: 'vertical',
            x: 0,
          y:30,
            symbolHeight: 12,
            itemMarginBottom: 1,
            symbolWidth: 25,
            symbolRadius: 1,

            title: {
        text: ' Issues<br/><span style="font-size: 9px; color: #666; font-weight: normal">Total: 2000</span>' 
        //Click event on 2000 
        // call donut service's get total info. Need not have to pass any variable. 

    },


        },




          series: [{



            data: [{ name: 'AA Test_long_name_for_testing_purpose', value: '5,044', y: 5044 },
                    { name: 'BB Test', value: '5,044', y: 5044 },
                     { name: 'CC Test', value: '5,355', y: 5355 },
                    { name: 'DD Test', value: '5,672', y: 56721 },
                    { name: 'EE Test', value: '9,874', y: 98743 }],
            allowPointSelect: true
        }]
    };
}
```

Comment: Cheers man, thank you so much for this. It works like a charm.

Comment: Can we highlight the name background with some color instead of name getting highlighted. like the way it happens when we hover over the legend, the whole legend row gets a grey color background.

Comment: You can definitely play around with the css of that class applied.